# How to add Displace Image Filter effect on UIImage in iOS for iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, image-processing

I am trying to implement Displace (Distortion)  Image Filter effect on `UIImage`. How can I do this? Please suggest.

Source Image:
[image]

After Displace Image Effect (Distortion)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try examples provide in [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage),

I haven't checked myself, but maybe you will find something useful.

Comment: thanx for reply. But which class of GPUImage gives this type of Image effect.

Comment: Is it too hard to check it all for Yourself? I'm just providing at least place where to dig. But You have to dig yourself. Good luck!